# SQL Timestamp -> 1970

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to output the time, when my form saves a input. Here is my code, my DB settings and my output. I hope someone can help me. I am new in PHP and SQL and I am very proud so far. :)

```
<?php 
$dbLink=mysql_connect('','',''); 
mysql_select_db('',$dbLink); 

$abfrage='SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY Zeit DESC'; 
$ergebnis=mysql_query($abfrage); 
?>

<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".date("d.m.Y",$row->Zeit)."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='".$row->url."' target='_blank'>".$row->text."</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$row->kategorie."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

[image: Here are my table settings]

[image: This is the time in my table]

[image: This is how it looks at my website]

Comment: `echo (new DateTime($row->Zeit))->format('d.m.Y');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date()` requires a Unix Timestamp as its second parameter. You need to convert that MySQL datetime value into a Unix Timestamp using `strtotime()`before `date()` can transform it:

```
echo "<td>".date("d.m.Y",strtotime($row->Zeit))."</td>";
```

Comment: @ Rizier123: I know, but I have to wait some minutes. :)

Comment: @John Conde - Is there a possibility that the time get +1 hour?

Comment: Sure. You can do that in your query by using `date_add()` to add that hour or you can add it in various ways using PHP. I'm sure a quick search of this site will give you that code.

Comment: @JohnConde `date("H:i - d.m.y",strtotime($row->Zeit) + 60*60)` That's the trick. Thank you. :)